# AccountManagerCallback is not working below kitkat and it is working fine in Kitkat

Tags: android, accountmanager

I'm using this code to authenticate the user with the synced email account of the device. And the callback is fired in Kitkat but when checked with below versions the callback is not working

```
AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> accountManagerCallback = new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
        @Override
        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
            Toast.makeText(ThirdActivity.this, "Fired!!!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
accountManager.confirmCredentials(accounts[0], null, this,
                accountManagerCallback, null);
```

Used permissons :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
```